# volatile variable in segger embedded studio with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I use SES import my keil MDK project, and my keil project work well. With SES, i have a problem, that is, i have a global variable like this:

```
uint32_t               g_ulMainLoopCounter = 0;
```

and i decrease it in timmer isr:

```
if  (g_ulMainLoopCounter > 0)
{
    g_ulMainLoopCounter--;
}
```

in my main function, i wait until 'g_ulMainLoopCounter' decrease to 0:

```
int main(void)
{   
    system_init();                                      //init timer etc...

    g_ulMainLoopCounter = 500;
    while (g_ulMainLoopCounter)
    {
    }

   ....
}
```

now the problem is , my code after 'while' will never be executioned, even 'g_ulMainLoopCounter' decrease to 0. This work well in keil.

Then, if i use 'volatile' qualifier for 'g_ulMainLoopCounter', it works, the code then like this:

```
volatile uint32_t g_ulMainLoopCounter = 0;
```

My optimization level set to none, means do not optimize my code.

I know use 'volatile' qualifier is a better way, but 'g_ulMainLoopCounter' is just only a example, there are lots of variables which used like "g_ulMainLoopCounter" (means multi-access variable, change the value in a function or isr and comparison in other function)in my program, must i check every variable in my program and determine if the variable is needed use 'volatile' qualifier? If so, i think that's too difficult.Is there any easy solutions?

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *5.1.2.3 Program execution 5 When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a signal, the
values of objects that are neither lock-free atomic objects nor of type volatile
sig_atomic_t are unspecified, as is the state of the floating-point environment. The
value of any object modified by the handler that is neither a lock-free atomic object nor of
type volatile sig_atomic_t becomes indeterminate when the handler exits[...]*

Answer (score 0):

You seem to know the meaning of `volatile`.
Your question is mainly whether you should consciously consider it for all your variables.
The answer is: Yes.

If that seems too difficult, or accidentally, just leave the `volatile` away and only start thinking about it when something does not work as desired.
You might however finally find out that this solution is actually very hard.
Maybe your question was caused by this experience.

The good news is that it will become easier, with experience.
At some point, you will read code, or write it, and feel a shiver going down the back. With more experience you will be able to tell the difference between the "volatile is missing"-shiver and e.g. the "variable is not initialised"-shiver.

Comment: Yes, i know what 'volatile' mean. I use keil MDK which use ARM-CC before, and never use GCC, and i never use 'volatile' qualifier for multi-access variables because it's no problem for ARM-CC, program works well.  Now, i use GCC, the problem appear, is ARM-CC not rigorous enough? I know use 'volatile' qualifier is a better way, i just do not want use 'volatile' qualifier for all global variables or members of global struct variable, because there will be lots of  [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers] warning, so i need to know when i must use 'volatile' qualifier, and when don't.

Comment: When i access the variable in different threads(include ISR), i must use 'volatile' qualifier for the variable, and if i access the variable in different functions in the same thread, i don't need use 'volatile' qualifier for it, is that right? So, if the system do not use OS,  means there is only one tread except ISR, so i only need use 'volatile' qualifier for the variables which multi-access by ISR and the main loop, is that so?

Comment: The question when it is safe to omit `volatile` is a separate one and complex.